# Trying to parse JSON in Apple Script using JSONhelper

Tags: json, applescript

AppleScript is a little bit too plain English sometimes, I wish if I could just go like: `somearray.someotherarray.0.item`

Anyway, this is what I have got:

```
set q to "Terminator"

tell application "JSON Helper"
    set json to fetch JSON from "https://yts.mx/api/v2/list_movies.json?quality=1080p&limit=1&query_term=" & q
    
    set value1 to the contents of the result's data's movie's torrent's 1st item's URL
end tell
```

Can anyone tell me how can I get the first torrent url from this json? It would be such a cool alfred workflow for downloading movies..
Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tell the movies's first item in json's |data| to tell ¬
    {its title_long} & its torrents's items to set ¬
    Film to {name:1st item, |720p|:the |url| of ¬
    the 2nd item, |1080p|:the |url| of the 3rd item}
```

In this particular case, the variable `Film` will store the following information as a `record`:

```
{name:"Terminator: Dark Fate (2019)", 
|720p|:"https://yts.mx/torrent/download/...", 
|1080p|:"https://yts.mx/torrent/download/..."}
```

(Obviously, I truncated the URLs myself; they appear in full in the actual object returned.)